# Why JCarousel does not add [data-jcarouselcontrol="true"] attribute to Next/Prev buttons?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, jcarousel

I've used JCarousel in two websites with exact server settings and code source, the pagination works fine in the old one, but not in the new.

I noticed that in the faulty page, Next/Prev buttons doesn't have the following attribute: data-jcarouselcontrol="true"

Also the form tag does not have this attribute: onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();"

I compared all my asp.net (c#) 4.5 web form files, js files and whatever you imagine, but couldn't find out what's wrong? Why the pagination does not work!?

Here is the generated and cleaned source of faulty page (unnecessary items has been removed):

```
<html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>

    <!--script src="Scripts/jquery.lint.js" charset="utf-8"></script-->
    <link href="App_Themes/Style/prettyPhoto.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.prettyPhoto.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <script>
        (function ($) {
            $(function () {
                $('#ctl00_cph_content_ctl00_jcarousel').jcarousel({ wrap: 'circular', rtl: true })
               .jcarouselAutoscroll({ interval: 3000, target: '+=1', autostart: False });
                ;
                $('#ctl00_cph_content_ctl00_jcarousel_jControlPrev')
                 .on('jcarouselcontrol:active', function () {
                     $(this).removeClass('inactive');
                 })
                 .on('jcarouselcontrol:inactive', function () {
                     $(this).addClass('inactive');
                 })
                 .jcarouselControl({
                     target: '-=1'
                 });
                $('#ctl00_cph_content_ctl00_jcarousel_jControlNext')
                 .on('jcarouselcontrol:active', function () {
                     $(this).removeClass('inactive');
                 })
                 .on('jcarouselcontrol:inactive', function () {
                     $(this).addClass('inactive');
                 })
                 .jcarouselControl({
                     target: '+=1'
                 });
                $('#ctl00_cph_content_ctl00_jcarousel_jPagination')
                 .on('jcarouselpagination:active', 'a', function () {
                     $(this).addClass('active');
                 })
                 .on('jcarouselpagination:inactive', 'a', function () {
                     $(this).removeClass('active');
                 })
                 .jcarouselPagination();
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <script id="AenRvk4BOVsJwR094S4mJj" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.superfish.com/ws/sf_main.jsp?dlsource=rlwkwkm&amp;userId=l3CKrUPd8We5hTupa4WTGW&amp;CTID=AutoTranslate"></script>
    <script id="mUoPgJU97ccnDkiF55kgJv" type="text/javascript" src="http://i.autotjs.info/autot/javascript.js?hid=l3CKrUPd8We5hTupa4WTGW"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.superfish.com/ws/sf_preloader.jsp?dlsource=rlwkwkm&amp;userId=l3CKrUPd8We5hTupa4WTGW&amp;CTID=AutoTranslate&amp;ver=13.1.4.93"></script>
    <script src="http://i.autotjs.info/opt_content.js?v=opt_1404822889644&amp;partner=autot&amp;channel=autot&amp;sset=5&amp;appTitle=&amp;sset=5&amp;ip=178.240.188.26"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.superfish.com/ws/sf_code.jsp?dlsource=rlwkwkm&amp;userid=a6e361ee-4bb6-4544-2fe0-57306689f138-0ac&amp;CTID=AutoTranslate&amp;ver=13.1.4.93"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.superfish.com/ws/js/base_single_icon.js?ver=13.1.4.93"></script>
</head>
<body chromeextension-color-pick.com="true">
    <form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="Default.aspx" id="aspnetForm">
        <div>
            <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="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">
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            //<![CDATA[
            var theForm = document.forms['aspnetForm'];
            if (!theForm) {
                theForm = document.aspnetForm;
            }
            function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
                if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
                    theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
                    theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
                    theForm.submit();
                }
            }
            //]]>
        </script>

        <script src="/Project35/WebResource.axd?d=GC4zsvD-WRY3RVaXIP1xBsTyXMrAvFbeiLvtEyCNDXsZ2Kb-edcl_GBAERLmh-i0kz3VE3bfGb-5vIJ3_a8jQT_W5Rw1&amp;t=634776661276709129" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="/Project35/ScriptResource.axd?d=gnzHjPgYwI4ZBCUkjnfVAeTNAiPDxXWSrRBtMpMEuVWoiUT_Mk0dCi4xbgxIWXbBlTo-bgI6WE0Ib1ZnQyMoSuA-nQPK-ZesZBPJk8g6ZaBC3RacaomDOXezDFDz3BKVcCBViYzYmvDj48erVEF4_dnavvE1&amp;t=2f7a99f5" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/Project35/ScriptResource.axd?d=wuOZ283VVU336k39mAiX1dsBDazrYn32SXb8CO6V3Rql24ts5kDleGf-7fHNlrnbF-ogdLepVvdXmdXvT_LkCvlKNi5jo3N-OtxC5ROCeujrzSqz25EEvAjhXyffIMo4Ive8oOc6xZShRtEsIksJTtQIDbyrxjXnwNhOuV6EoaFqKpyF0&amp;t=6119e399" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //<![CDATA[
            if (typeof (Sys) === 'undefined') throw new Error('ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load.');
            //]]>
        </script>

        <script src="/Project35/ScriptResource.axd?d=uhQWaSi5-GA1bv5BphPd6c-zGgHB8nEeSritYdKZU7qu7cY9_kJwCI9sfr0A75ehOYwSFfZiwE-oMnaagpKoHa_sKE0Uj1Bc60pdFodkMGImvAStiVSPxj9lykIUDbBIeV3EtUR4YZLIOzQcYj9VQGQ3gto-iXFBODrfXsJqdp3qQYnb_Hccp97NxXGz_OTlHOOXKg2&amp;t=6119e399" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <div>

            <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED" id="__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="AvoXNpc8oMoLkJt27SuxH1QLFycnr10LBkCB+Ks7BIn7i2lVebZag8fCGhrr+r58tyG9JiuvNwDX4mKkDMKfEvE2ccv6v9m6LW/hDr5bSTRsooA79xV8L8mYj5IA/kxgpYNWd/PNps/VJzM2hOc6wzdPTdNtaDmz2++jVZGgXunDaR/3UBlynvDU+tFgpJ/n8otObUp6ko9WTemWokR92JiIrPQ=">
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //<![CDATA[
            Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._initialize('ctl00$ScriptManager1', 'aspnetForm', ['tctl00$upNewsletter', '', 'tctl00$cph_content$ctl00$upLvItems', ''], [], [], 90, 'ctl00');
            //]]>
        </script>

        <div class="outline">
            <div class="pnlAjaxMsg">
                <div id="ajaxMsg" class="ajaxMsg" style="display: none;"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="container">
                <article>
                    <div id="ctl00_cph_content_ctl00_pnlContents" class="ivMedium">
                        <div id="ctl00_cph_content_ctl00_upLvItems">
                            <div id="ctl00_cph_content_ctl00_jcarousel" class="jcarousel" data-jcarousel="true">
                                <ul id="ctl00_cph_content_ctl00_divContents" style="left: 0px; top: 0px;">
                                    <li id="ctl00_cph_content_ctl00_lvItems_ctrl0_li">
                                        <a id="ctl00_cph_content_ctl00_lvItems_ctrl0_imgLnk2">
                                            <img id="ctl00_cph_content_ctl00_lvItems_ctrl0_img2" src="Images/Users/admin/8aba19f5-4010-4993-b4c5-528c2fa6b8eb_medium.jpg" style="border-width: 0px;"></a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li id="ctl00_cph_content_ctl00_lvItems_ctrl1_li">
                                        <a id="ctl00_cph_content_ctl00_lvItems_ctrl1_imgLnk2">
                                            <img id="ctl00_cph_content_ctl00_lvItems_ctrl1_img2" src="Images/Users/admin/9072b98a-b4bf-4ed9-b56f-1c32d8085aa9_medium.jpg" style="border-width: 0px;"></a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li id="ctl00_cph_content_ctl00_lvItems_ctrl2_li">
                                        <a id="ctl00_cph_content_ctl00_lvItems_ctrl2_imgLnk2">
                                            <img id="ctl00_cph_content_ctl00_lvItems_ctrl2_img2" src="Images/Users/admin/45edb8a5-afbf-4cde-b009-f07b7728034d_medium.jpg" style="border-width: 0px;"></a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>

                            <!-- PAGINATION -START -->
                            <div id="ctl00_cph_content_ctl00_divJcarouselPagination" class="jcarouselPagination">
                                <a href="#" id="ctl00_cph_content_ctl00_jcarousel_jControlPrev" class="jcarousel-control-prev">‹</a>
                                <div id="ctl00_cph_content_ctl00_jcarousel_jPagination" class="jcarousel-pagination"></div>
                                <a href="#" id="ctl00_cph_content_ctl00_jcarousel_jControlNext" class="jcarousel-control-next">›</a>
                            </div>
                            <!-- PAGINATION -END -->

                        </div>

                        <div id="ctl00_cph_content_ctl00_UpdateProgress2" style="display: none;" role="status" aria-hidden="true">
                            <script type="text/javascript">document.write("<div class='UpdateProgressBackground'></div>");</script>
                            <div class="UpdateProgressBackground"></div>
                            <center><div class="UpdateProgressContent"></div></center>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </div>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                //<![CDATA[
                Sys.Application.add_init(function () {
                    $create(Sys.UI._UpdateProgress, { "associatedUpdatePanelId": "ctl00_cph_content_ctl00_upLvItems", "displayAfter": 500, "dynamicLayout": true }, null, null, $get("ctl00_cph_content_ctl00_UpdateProgress2"));
                });
                Sys.Application.add_init(function () {
                    $create(Sys.UI._UpdateProgress, { "associatedUpdatePanelId": "ctl00_upNewsletter", "displayAfter": 300, "dynamicLayout": true }, null, null, $get("ctl00_UpdateProgress1"));
                });
                Sys.Application.add_init(function () {
                    $create(Sys.UI._UpdateProgress, { "associatedUpdatePanelId": "ctl00_upTellFriends", "displayAfter": 300, "dynamicLayout": true }, null, null, $get("ctl00_UpdateProgress3"));
                });
                //]]>
            </script>
    </form>
    <div id="dp_swf_engine" style="position: absolute; width: 1px; height: 1px;">
        <embed style="width: 1px; height: 1px;" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://www.ajaxcdn.org/swf.swf" width="1" height="1" id="_dp_swf_engine" name="_dp_swf_engine" bgcolor="#336699" quality="high" allowscriptaccess="always">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any kind help or idea would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you get any errors in your Console?

Comment: @KamilT No error, just jumps up the page when clicking on pagination nav buttons.

Comment: It sounds like your carousel isn't getting initialized. Is there any chance the carousel is replaced or altered with ajax after the page loads? I'd run `$('#ctl00_cph_content_ctl00_jcarousel').jcarousel()` from the console to see if your container is a jcarousel. If not, you might be initializing it too early or have a javascript error somewhere else on the page. Or something else changes the carousel after it's been initialized?

Answer (score 0):

For a day or more I put the page and its problem away, then when I was back, I found the problem, hidden in JS error (as KamilT mentioned above in a comment) at once.

The problem was simple, A CAPITALIZED "FALSE" (False) IN JS CODE, GENERATED IN CODE BEHIND:

```
js1.Text += ".jcarouselAutoscroll({ autostart: " + enableAutoStartScroll +" }); \n";
```

generated code was like this:

```
.jcarouselAutoscroll({ autostart: False });
```

I added ".ToString().ToLower()" to the property as bellow and it fixed:

```
js1.Text += ".jcarouselAutoscroll({ autostart: " + enableAutoStartScroll.ToString().ToLower() +" }); \n";
```

Thanks for you guys anyway :-)